# In how many ways can we rearrrange the digits: $0,1,2,\ldots,9$ if the first digit should be $>1$ and the last one $<8$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can we rearrrange the digits: $0,1,2,\ldots,9$ if the first digit should be $>1$ and the last one $<8$?

Given answer by the book : $10! - 2 \cdot 9! - 2 \cdot 9! + 4 \cdot 8!$ .

> I probably miss something here. My approach: There are $3$ ways to violate the constraints

1. If the first digit is $\leq 1$ . Then we have $2$ choices for the first digit, $8$ for the last one ( since it's less than $8$, the last digit $\in [0,7]$, and since we picked already two digits out of $10$ available there are $8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \ldots \cdot 1 = 8!$ for the other digits of the arrangement . In total : $N(c1)=2 \cdot 8 \cdot 8!$
2. If the 10th digit is $\geq 8$ . This can happen in two ways ($8$ or $9$), we also have $8$ choices for the first one and $8!$ for everything else . In total : $N(c2)=2 \cdot 8 \cdot 8!$
3. Both 1 and 2 cases :  If the first digit is $\leq 1$ and the 10th digit is $\geq 8$  . This can happen in $N(c1 \wedge c2)=2 \cdot 2 \cdot 8!$ ways.

Without constraint : $10!$

> Hence , from inclusion - exclusion principle There are  \begin{align*} N(c1 \lor c2)) & = N - (N(c1) + N(c2) - N(c1 \wedge c2))\\ & = 10! - 2 \cdot 8 \cdot 8! -2 \cdot 8 \cdot 8! + 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 8!\\ & = 10! - 2 \cdot 8 \cdot 8! -2 \cdot 8 \cdot 8! + 4 \cdot 8!\end{align*}

With the help of some fellow people here , I realised my mistake: If I want to define the fact $N(c1)$ as the case where only the first and only this digit violates the constraint then sure I can do it as long as  I then write $ N(c1 \wedge c2) = 0$. Otherwise, we can define $N(c1)$ as the case where the first digit violates the constraint without wondering about the last and after we make sure we don't count twice, since $N(c1 \wedge c2) = 0$ this time

Comment: Note that in initially stating the problem you give strict inequalities, but switch to weak inequalities in your case analysis.  Counting the exceptions (ways to "violate the constraints") is a sound approach though.

Comment: Are you considering *ten* a digit for a total of eleven digits?  Ordinarily we reserve the word "digits" to refer to $0,1,2,\dots,9$ only.

Comment: @JMoravitz you are right , i fixed the title

Comment: Now... as for your attempt... using your notation you seem to have confused $N(c1)$ with $N(c1\wedge \neg c2)$.  When counting $N(c1)$ we do not concern ourselves with $c2$ at all here.  We allow it to be satisfied or violated.  So, when counting $N(c1)$ you say "*we have 2 choices for the first digit, 8 for the last one*" that is incorrect.. we in fact have *nine* choices for the last one... the only restriction here being that it not be whatever was picked for the first digit.

Comment: Then you missed that subtracting a negative number is the same as adding a positive number, so the final term should have been added, not subtracted.  This leads to the correct solution which the book offered of $10!-2\cdot \color{red}{9}\cdot 8!-2\cdot \color{red}{9}\cdot 8!\color{red}{+}2\cdot 2\cdot 8!$

Comment: @JMoravitz I am confused about the part you say that we have 9 choices for the last digit . Shouldn't we follow the constraint? I defined  $N(c1)$  as the case when only the first digit takes an "illegal" value..

Comment: @JMoravitz yes yes I just missed the + when i wrote it , no more numberical errors , right now

Comment: In that case, then as BrianMScott points out below, your $c1\wedge c2$ is when simultaneously the first digit is the *only* illegal value *and* that the last digit is *also* the *only* illegal value... but both can't be true simultaneously.  If one is the only illegal value and the other is *also* the only illegal value, then you have two illegal values at the same time, contradicting that each individually was the *only* illegal value.  Your $N(c1\wedge c2)$ should have been zero since it is impossible to have both first and last simultaneously be the one and only illegal values.

Comment: @JMoravitz oh i think  i got it. Let me paraphrase what you said to make sure I understand: If as I said $N(c1)$ was the case : that only the first digit and only this violates the constraint , that and N(c2) accordingly for the last one.. Then how there is such a chance both of them happen? you made that really clear thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112310/discussion-between-brucebanner-and-jmoravitz).

Answer (score 3):

Your first is not simply the number of arrangements that violate the restriction on the first digit: it’s the number that violate that restriction and do **not** violate the restriction on the last digit. Similarly, your second calculation yields the number of arrangements that violate the condition on the last digit but **not** the condition on the first digit. This approach does not count any unwanted arrangement twice, so the total number of acceptable arrangements is simply $10!-2\cdot8\cdot8!-2\cdot8\cdot8!$, and this is indeed the same as the answer given:

$$\begin{align*}
10!-2\cdot8\cdot8!-2\cdot8\cdot8!&=(90-16-16)\cdot8!\\
&=58\cdot8!\\
&=(90-18-18+4)\cdot8!\\
&=10!-2\cdot9!-2\cdot9!+4\cdot8!\,.
\end{align*}$$

In the answer that you were given, the first $2\cdot9!$ is the number of arrangements that violate the condition on the first term **whether or not** they also violate the condition on the last digit, and the second is the number that violate the condition on the last term **whether or not** they also violate the condition on the first digit. When you do the calculation this way, you do count each arrangement that violates both conditions twice, so you have to add those back in; that’s what the $4\cdot8!$ term does.

Comment: I get the math you wrote  but intuitively I can't see  why this formula works .In reality there is chance that both the first and the second violate the constraint , in the formula $10! - 2*8*8!  -2*8*8! $ which term represents that case?

Comment: @brucebanner: That case doesn’t exist in that calculation, because each $2\cdot8\cdot8!$ counts only the arrangements that violate exactly one of the restrictions.

Comment: @It's like my mind doesn't want to digest it . So we build our facts , we define N(c1) as the fact where only the first digit violates the cosntraint, and N(c2) accordingly but for the last digit this time. We actually want to calculate :$(N(c1 \lor c2))'$ and because according to this system we defined : $N(c1 \land c2) = 0$ . So we get the correct answer .. Two different systems of facts , both work well if we follow strictly our definitions..

Comment: thanks for letting me identify my errors and getting a deeper insight into this problem!

Comment: @brucebanner: Yes. We can calculate the number $n_1$ that violate $c1$, ignoring $c2$ completely; the number $n_2$ that violate $c2$, ignoring $c1$ completely; and the number $n_b$ that violate both. Or we can calculate the number $m_1$ that violate **only** $c1$ and the number $m_2$ that violate **only** $c2$. In the first case the number of unwanted arrangements is $n_1+n_2-n_b$; in the second it’s $m_a+m_2$, because we didn’t count anything twice. Both ways work, and in this problem they’re about equally easy. You’re welcome!